# Aggregating to remove duplicates in a data table based on the minimum in one column

Tags: r, data.table

I am very new to the data.table package in R. The version of data.table is 1.8.2.

My data table has about 21 million rows so ideally I would love to use the data table method to solve my problem as it is the way to deal with big data these days. Below is the sample data and code:

```
samp_data <- data.frame(user1 = c(24, 24, 24, 56, 75, 75),
                        user2 = c(43, 43, 57, 34, 61, 61),  
                        amount1 = c(1, 4, 3, 2, 6, 8), 
                        amount2 = c(4, 7, 9, 3, 5, 6), 
                        PURCH_DATE_1 = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2012-04-29", 
                        "2012-03-02", "2012-06-15", "2012-03-17", "2012-09-25")), 
                        PURCH_DATE_2 = as.Date(c("2012-04-01", "2012-01-25", 
                        "2012-05-21","2012-08-18", "2012-04-03", "2012-10-29")))
samp_data$DIFF_DAYS <- abs(as.numeric(samp_data$PURCH_DATE_1-
samp_data$PURCH_DATE_2))
samp_data_new<-data.table(samp_data)
```

I would like to get back a data table that has the 7 original columns but where there are duplicate pairs in the user1 and user2 column, the row which has the minimum value in the DIFF_DAYS column will be kept.

Assuming that I have confused some of you with what I want, the code below contains the desired output:

```
samp_data_desired<-data.frame(user1=c(24,24,56,75),user2=c(43,57,34,61),
                              amount1=c(1,3,2,6),amount2=c(4,9,3,5),
                              PURCH_DATE_1=as.Date(c("2012-01-01","2012-03-02",
                              "2012-06-15","2012-03-17")),
                              PURCH_DATE_2=as.Date(c("2012-04-01","2012-05-21",
                              "2012-08-18","2012-04-03")),
                              DIFF_DAYS=c(91,80,64,17))
```

I know how to perform simple aggregations to find the mean, min and max for each user1 using the DT[, min(col1), by=user1] sort of idea but I was unable to successfully use the unique or duplicated functions. I tried:

```
samp_data_check <- data.table(samp_data, key=c("user1", "user2", 
                            "amount1", "amount2", "PURCH_DATE_1",
                            "PURCH_DATE_2"))
```

and

```
samp_data_test <- samp_data_check[, unique(DIFF_DAYS), by=c("user1", 
                  "user2", "amount1", "amount2", "PURCH_DATE_1", 
                  "PURCH_DATE_2")]
```

along with some variations but I'm getting horribly confused so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you update your version of `data.table`. The latest stable release is 1.8.8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First way I could think of (doesn't have much to do with `data.table` except setting key column to `DIFF_DAYS`). Assuming your `data.table` is DT:

```
setkey(DT, "DIFF_DAYS")
DT[!duplicated(DT[, c("user1", "user2")])]
```

---

Another method (more `data.table`):

```
setkey(DT, "user1", "user2", "DIFF_DAYS")
key.DT <- unique(DT[, 1:2])
DT[key.DT, mult = "first"]
```

Comment: Cheers for the answer Arun, it seemed like such an easy question but I just couldn't get it and it was driving me mad. Your solution is great and I very much appreciate the help

Comment: I'd be interested to know if there's a runtime difference between the two methods (don't count the time spent to set the key in both cases). If you can write back (on the 21 million rows), it'd be great!

Comment: Hi Arun, sorry for the delay in getting back, was busy in work. Original data set has 21,048,612 rows containing 7 numeric and 2 date columns. The second method took 3.180583 mins. The first method takes 2.419069 mins. Hope this helps and thanks again for the solution. Let me know if you need to know anything else.